# How to create a webservice client to a secure webservice at localhost

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have created a webservice and it has deployed on localhost. When I browse the WSDL using browser `https://localhost:8181/Test/TestOne?wsdl` it shows me the WSDL.

But when I try to create client program (I am using NetBeans 7.0) and give this URL for the WSDL URL, it shows me error message that wsdl **Problem with downloading wsdl or schema file....**. I tried editing the proxy to use system proxy settings also but no luck. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your server doesn't use a certificate signed by CA. So, you need to create a keystore with certificate and pass "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=" parameter to NetBeans.

Comment: I followed this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/WSIT_Security9.html#wp151774 ,and there it says **SSL come pre-configured with GlassFish**

Comment: But NetBeans know nothing about GlassFish certs.

Comment: I agree with you.Could you please show me how to do it in detail or post me a link to read and learn.Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Open the wizard for setting the attributes for the WebService: right mouse click on the Web Service reference in the client application, choose Edit WebService Attributes, go to Wsimport options tab, and correct the property wsdlLocation as follows:

```
from: https://<address>:8181/<ws-url>?wsdl
to: /META-INF/wsdl/<address>_8181/<ws-url>.wsdl
```

more info [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic38902.html)

Comment: No,I just stuck on the creation of the client.I am getting error in creating the client but not in consuming.But the question post you linked exactly same with my problem.